# exclude form elements from getelementbyid

Tags: javascript

```
function changemysize(myvalue) { 
    var div = document.getElementById( "content" );
    div.style.fontSize = myvalue + "em";
    document.cookie="mysize=" + myvalue;
}
```

This changes the size of all text in the content div, which is awesome.

It also changes the size of any form input fields, which is not so awesome.

What would be a good way to exclude HTML form fields that are within the "content" div from this function?

---------More Info----------

I am using this function in the header to dynamically change the font size of all text below the header.

```
<div id="adjust">Click to Adjust Size: 
    <span style="font-size: 1em;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changemysize(1);">A</a>
    </span>
    <span style="font-size: 1.2em;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changemysize(1.2);">A</a>
    </span>
    <span style="font-size: 1.4em;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changemysize(1.4);">A</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Since my header ends with `<div id="content" class="site-content">`, all page content gets sized including form fields.  Is there a way to exclude them?

Comment: This is a CSS problem, not a Javascript problem. Style the parent as you need to and override the font sizing in the children inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a CSS deal.  I ended up adding a set font size (had to be 'px' rather than 'em') to all form fields, which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the children's of the `div`, and then set their font-size individually, checking if they are a form `<input>` field or not, like this:

JavaScript:

```
// The code is self-explanatory, ask though if you need help
function changemysize(myvalue) { 
    var childs = document.getElementById( "content" ).children;

    for(var i = 0; childs[i]; i++){
        if(childs[i].tagName !== "form")
            childs[i].style.fontSize = myvalue + "em";
    }

    document.cookie="mysize=" + myvalue;
}

changemysize(20);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/C22Md/) (Notice the input field remains small)

Comment: Thanks but it was a CSS problem overall.  I ended up adding a font size (px) css attribute to all form fields, which did the trick.